Livewire2 reactive properties
i have a project written in l livewire2 and i have reached to the point i have to use reactive properties
but didn't find anything in v2 docs or how to achieve this kind of behaviour
what i want
to make location component that can add multiple locations
but the same time it accepts the locations from another component to sync locations and can be used in different components as well like orders or some things like this
the location itself is an array have 6 entries
but what i get mess of events and listeners and didn't achieve the goal

Post what have you tried
